# Determining all the functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with the property $f\bigl(x-f(y)\bigr) f\bigl(f(x)+y\bigr)=x f(x) - y f(y)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> Determine all the functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with the property that
> $$f\bigl(x-f(y)\bigr) f\bigl(f(x)+y\bigr)=x f(x) - y f(y)$$
> for any real numbers $x$ and $y$.

I managed to see that $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=-x$ are solutions, but I don't know how to prove that.

Comment: $f(x)=0$ is also a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's straightforward to verify that the constant zero function, the identity function and the negation function are all solutions to the functional equation
$$ f \bigl ( x - f ( y ) \bigr ) f \bigl ( f ( x ) + y \bigr ) = x f ( x ) - y f ( y ) \tag 0 \label 0 $$
over $ \mathbb R $. We prove that any $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ satisfying \eqref{0} for all $ x , y \in \mathbb R $ is of one of those forms. Letting $ y = x $ in \eqref{0}, we have
$$ f \bigl ( x - f ( x ) \bigr ) f \bigl ( f ( x ) + x \bigr ) = 0 \tag 1 \label 1 $$
for all $ x \in \mathbb R $. For any $ x \in \mathbb R $, if $ f \bigl ( x - f ( x ) \bigr ) = 0 $, then setting $ y = x - f ( x ) $ in \eqref{0}, we get $ f ( x ) \bigl ( f ( x ) - x \bigr ) = 0 $. Similarly, for any $ y \in \mathbb R $, if $ f \bigl ( f ( y ) + y \bigr ) = 0 $, then letting $ x = f ( y ) + y $ in \eqref{0}, we get $ f ( y ) \bigl ( f ( y ) + y \bigr ) = 0 $. Combining these with \eqref{1}, we get
$$ f ( x ) \bigl ( f ( x ) - x \bigr ) \bigl ( f ( x ) + x \bigr ) = 0 \tag 2 \label 2 $$
for all $ x \in \mathbb R $. In particular, we get $ f ( 0 ) = 0 $ by putting $ x = 0 $ in \eqref{2}. Letting $ y = 0 $ in \eqref{0}, we can see that
$$ f ( x ) \ne 0 \implies f \bigl ( f ( x ) \bigr ) = x \tag 3 \label 3 $$
for all $ x \in \mathbb R $. Also, setting $ x = 0 $ in \eqref{0}, we have
$$ f ( y ) \ne 0 \implies f \bigl ( - f ( y ) \bigr ) = - y $$
for all $ y \in \mathbb R $, applying $ f $ to both sides of which, we get
$$ f ( y ) \ne 0 \implies f ( - y ) = - f ( y ) \tag 4 \label 4 $$
for all $ y \in \mathbb R \setminus \{ 0 \} $, using \eqref{3}. \eqref{4} implies $ f ( - y ) \ne 0 \iff f ( y ) \ne 0 $ for all $ y \in \mathbb R \setminus \{ 0 \} $, which then using \eqref{4} and $ f ( 0 ) = 0 $, implies that $ f $ is an odd function.

Now, assume that there is $ a \in \mathbb R \setminus \{ 0 \} $ with $ f ( a ) \ne 0 $. Then, $ 0 $ will be the only $ y \in \mathbb R $ for which $ f ( y ) = 0 $. To see this, assume $ f ( y ) = 0 $ and let $ x = a $ in \eqref{0} to get $ f \bigl ( f ( a ) + y \bigr ) = a $, and using \eqref{3} conclude
$$ f ( a ) + y = f \Bigl ( f \bigl ( f ( a ) + y \bigr ) \Bigr ) = f ( a ) \text . $$
This, together with \eqref{2} shows $ f ( x ) \in \{ - x , x \} $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{ 0 \} $. Equivalently, we have $ f ( x ) \in \{ - k x , k x \} $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{ 0 \} $, where $ k = \frac { f ( a ) } a \in \{ - 1 , 1 \} $. Note that $ f ( k x ) = k f ( x ) $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R $, since $ f $ is odd, and also $ f ( x ) ^ 2 = x ^ 2 $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R $. Now, if $ f ( x ) = - k x $ for some $ x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{ 0 \} $, then using \eqref{0} and \eqref{3} we get
\begin{align*}
k a ^ 2 + 2 k a x + k x ^ 2
& = k ( a + x ) ^ 2 \\
& = k f ( a + x ) ^ 2 \\
& = f \bigl ( k ( a + x ) \bigr ) f ( a + x ) \\
& = f \bigl ( k a - ( - k x ) \bigr ) f ( a + x ) \\
& = f \bigl ( f ( a ) - f ( x ) \bigr ) f \Bigl ( f \bigl ( f ( a ) \bigr ) + x \Bigr ) \\
& = f ( a ) f \bigl ( f ( a ) \bigr ) - x f ( x ) \\
& = ( k a ) a - x ( - k x ) \\
& = k a ^ 2 + k x ^ 2 \text ,
\end{align*}
which leads to a contradiction. As we also have $ f ( 0 ) = k \cdot 0 $, we must have $ f ( x ) = k x $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R $. Therefore, the only nonzero solutions of \eqref{0} over $ \mathbb R $ are the identity function and the negation function.

Comment: This answer features ideas from the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4324111/229831) by [Gargantuar](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/605973/gargantuar) and a now deleted answer, which was by the user [TomTom314](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/553125/tomtom314), if I remember correctly. Both of the mentioned answers had flaws, and the posters were noted about that in the comments. As one got deleted and the other did not get correct or complete by editing for a long time, I decided to post this one.

Comment: Ah, the key insight seemed to be the line right above equation 4: "applying $f$ to both sides" that let you figure out its an odd function

Answer (score -1):

For $x=y$ we have
$$
f(x-f(x)) \times f(f(x)+x)) = 0.
$$
Thus, $f(x-f(x)) = 0$ or $f(x+f(x)) = 0$.

- Case 1, $f(x-f(x)) = 0$: Plugging in $y = x-f(x)$ in the original equation yields
  $$
  f(x-f(x-f(x))) \times f(f(x)+x-f(x)) = xf(x) - yf(x-f(x)) \\
  \implies f(x) \times f(x) = xf(x) \iff f(x) \times (f(x)-x) = 0.
  $$
  Therefore $f(x) = 0$ and $f(x) = x$ are possible solutions.
- Case 2, $f(x+f(x)) = 0$: Plugging in $x = y+f(y)$ in the original equation yields
  $$
  f(y+f(y)-f(y)) \times f(f(y+f(y))+y) = xf(y+f(y)) - yf(y) \\
  \implies f(y) \times f(y) = -yf(y) \iff f(y) \times (f(y)+y) = 0.
  $$
  Therefore $f(y) = 0$ and $f(y) = -y$ are possible solutions.

Checking verifies all three solutions.

Comment: For case 1 (and case 2 as well just with a negative) couldn't you have $f(x)$ equal to $x$ on the irrationals and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: @QC_QAOA You're right, it didn't even occured to me. The first displayed equation is also vague for that matter. Do you know how one can fix this?

Comment: I don't think there is a fix since such a function satisfies the original functional equation (at least according to my quick math)

Comment: Actually that's not quite true, if $f(x)=x$ for rational $x$ and $f(x)=0$ for irrational $x$, you get for rational $x$ and irrational $y$: $0=x^2$ for all rational $x$, which is wrong, since $\text{rational} + \text{irrational} = \text{irrational}$.

Comment: Oh your right, my bad. Hmm, then maybe your proof can be salvaged by following this line of reasoning: divide the real line into two subsets and then prove that if you make $f(x)$ $x$ on one subset and $0$ on the other it doesn't satisfy the functional. Same thing for case 2

Comment: *"Checking verifies all three solutions"* Which three solutions? So far, this answer shows that for every $x\in\Bbb{R}$ you have $f(x)\in\{0,x,-x\}$. Indeed making the same choice for all $x$ yields three nice solutions, but you have not excluded the many others.

Comment: @QC_QAOA There is a way to salvage the proof. If you're still interested, you can take a look at my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4324111/229831).